# Sharepoint online - Custom activity

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow-activity

We have a couple custom workflow activities, made with visual studio, which are working fine. We can use these activities from Sharepoint Designer en deploy them on Sharepoint 2010.

Now we need these custom activities to work in SharePoint online. I converted the solution to a sandboxed solution and created a package succesfully. Added the package in SharePoint online and activated it.
The problem now is that the custom activities are not showing up in Sharepoint designer. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

First, please check that you do not forget activate a feature.
Second, ensure that you selected "SharePoint 2010 Workflow" as platform type in "create workflow" dialog.